# Show that a function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, integration

Let K be bounded and continuous and bounded on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and let $f$ be Lebesgue integrable on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Show that the function $g$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ by

$g(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} K(tx)f(x)dx$

is well defined and continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Well defined:

$g(t) \leq |g(t)| \leq |\int K(tx)f(x)dx| \leq \int |K(tx)||f(x)|dx \leq N\int|f(x)|dx < \infty $,

where $N = \sup \{ |K(x)| : x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \}$.

Now prove it is continuous, I think I have come up with a raher complicated approach.

Since $f$ is integrable, we have for a positive number $M \in \mathbb{R}$ that

$\int_{B(0,M) \cap\mathbb{R}^{n}} |f(x)|dx = \int |f(x)| dx - \epsilon'$,

where $B(0,M)$ is a ball in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with center $0$ and radius $M$.

Now, since $K$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, it is uniformly continuous on the compact set $B(0,M) \cap\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Letting $|\frac{t_{1} - t_{0}}{M} | < \frac{\delta}{M}, \delta > 0$,

we get that on this compact subset

$|g(\frac{t_{1}}{M}) - g(\frac{t_{0}}{M}) | = |\int_{B(0,M) \cap\mathbb{R}^{n}} (K(\frac{t_{1}x}{M}) - K(\frac{t_{0}x}{M}))f(x)dx| $.

Since $||\frac{t_{1}x}{M} - \frac{t_{0}x}{M}|| = |\frac{t_{1}}{M} - \frac{t_{0}}{M}|$ $||x|| < \delta $ ,

$|K(\frac{t_{1}x}{M}) - K(\frac{t_{0}x}{M})| < \epsilon$  $\forall x \in B(0,M)\cap \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and we get

$|\int_{B(0,M) \cap\mathbb{R}^{n}} (K(\frac{t_{1}x}{M}) - K(\frac{t_{0}x}{M}))f(x)dx| \leq \int_{B(0,M) \cap\mathbb{R}^{n}} \epsilon|f(x)| dx =\epsilon (\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} |f(x)|dx  - \epsilon')$.

Since we can make $\epsilon$ and $\epsilon'$ arbitrary small, $g$ is continuous.

Now this seems to me like a complicated solution (if it is valid), but at the moment I can't come up with something simpler. I appreciate feedback on my approach, whether my proof is correct or if something is wrong.

A simpler solution would also be nice!

Thanks in advance!

/Erik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For continuity you can apply the **Dominated convergence theorem**:

Consider a $t\in\mathbb R$ and a sequence $t_n\to t$. Then $$g(t_n) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} K(t_nx)f(x)dx$$
Let $h_n(x)=K(t_nx)f(x)$. It is apparent that $h_n\to h=K(tx)f(x)$ since $K$ is continuous.

Also $|h_n(x)|=|K(t_nx)||f(x)|\leq \sup|K(x)|\cdot |f(x)|=N|f(x)|$. Now note that $N|f(x)| $ is integrable, therefore the dominated convergence theorem applies:

$$g(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} K(tx)f(x)dx=\int_{\mathbb R^n}
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}K(t_nx)f(x)dx=$$
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty }\int_{\mathbb R^n}K(t_nx)f(x)dx=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}g(t_n)$$thus $g$ is continuous.

Comment: Thanks, that was certainly easier than my try. However, what do you think about my approach? Is it correct or do I have to modify it?

Comment: Who do you integrate on $B(0,M)\cap\mathbb R^n$? The integral must be on $\mathbb R^n$